# Create Access Level as function in Node Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, rbac

I'm trying to create access levels in Node.js using Session.  So for example, if the username is "test" it can view a certain page.  If the username is "admin" it cannot view that same page. The username is stored in MySQL table "accounts".  The table has the column attribute "username". Been trying to try different things but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's my JS code:

```
app.get('/ViewPage', function(request, response) {
    var connection = request.app.get('pool');

    if (request.session.loggedin) {
    var username;

    connection.query('SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = test', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (username == "test") {
            // do the command here
        } else if (username == "admin"){
            response.redirect('/');
        }   
    });
    } else {
        response.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Edit: 
I updated my code as follows but it keeps looping to the "Admin cannot view this page" else if block.

```
app.get('/Create_Award', function (request, response) {
var connection = request.app.get('pool');

    if (request.session.loggedin) {
    connection.query('SELECT username FROM accounts', function (error, results, fields) {
    { account: results[0] };
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            if (results[0].username === "test") {
                connection.query('SELECT accounts.id, accounts.username, awardType.id as awardTypeId, awardType.title FROM accounts JOIN awardType WHERE username = ?', [request.session.username], function(error, results, fields) {
                    response.render('Create_Award.html', { account: results[0], data: results });
                    console.log('Test account.');
                }); //2nd connection
            }
            else if (results[0].username === "admin") {
                response.redirect('/');
                console.log('Admin cannot view this page.');
            }
            else {
                response.redirect('/');
            }
        }
    }); //1st connection
    } else {
        response.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. where is "username" defined? 2. "else if" is unreachable. 3. you are missing "else" in connection.query

Answer (score 0):

You are never populating your `var username` as it will always will be `undefined` and your code will go to `else` block

```
       app.get('/ViewPage', function (request, response) {
    var connection = request.app.get('pool');

    if (request.session.loggedin) {

        connection.query('SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username = test', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            else {
                if (results[0].username === "test") {
                    response.redirect('/myCustom');
                }
                else if (results[0].username === "admin") {
                    response.redirect('/');
                }
                else {
                    response.redirect('/');
                }
            }

        });
    } else {
        response.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Update your code and it will work

**Edit**- From what I can see understand from your updated code, the only thing incorrect is how you are using `res.render`. have a look [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render), it takes a `callback function`

Try this in your code and let me know if it works

```
response.render('Create_Award.html', { account: results[0], data: results },(err,html)=>{
          res.send(html)
});
```

Comment: Hello, I have updated my code as above but it keeps looping back to the "admin" else if block.

Comment: Check out the Edit

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get("/viewpage", async function(req, res) {
    var connection = req.app.get("pool");

    if (res.session.loggedin) {
        try {
            const result = await connection.query(
                "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = test"
            );
            if (result[0].username === "test") {
                //something
            } else if (result[0].username === "admin") {
                //something
            }
        } catch (error) {
            //You can log the error
            return res.redirect("/");
        }
    }
    return res.redirect("/");
});
```

There are some things to note here

**1)** Usage of async/await. It makes the code more readable, since queries can take some time to retrieve the data. Also encapsulating all of it inside a try/catch block so you can handle the error if there's any.

**2)** Your query callback wasn't used. You should use the results argument to retrieve the data in a callback-way.

**3)** While this is my opinion, always try to return a response, otherwise you may get "Routing error: Can't set headers after they are sent"